# Avoiding comma at the start of .CSV file in java

Tags: java, web, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I am scrapping data from a website and store it in CSV file. When the data gets in the CSV file it was getting the comma at the last place of every line. Somehow I  manage to handle it. But, now I am getting that comma at the very start of every line which is creating another column. Following is my code.

```
for (Iterator<Element> it = tdElements.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                    if (it.hasNext()) {
                        sb.append("  \n  ");
                    }
                    for (Iterator<Element> it2 = trElement2.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                        Element tdElement = it.next();
                        final String content = tdElement.text();

                        if (it2.hasNext()) {
                            sb.append("   ,   ");
                            sb.append(formatData(content));
                        }

                        if (!it2.hasNext()) {
                            String content1 = content.replaceAll(",$", " ");
                            sb.append(formatData(content1));
                            break;
                        } //to remove last placed Commas.

                    }

                    System.out.println(sb.toString());
                    sb.flush();
                    sb.close();
```

Result which I want e.g:        a,b,c,d,e
Result which I am getting e.g: ,a,b,c,d,e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(" ");
    for (Iterator<Element> it = tdElements.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                    if (it.hasNext()) {
                        sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);
                        sb.append("  \n  ");
                    }
                    for (Iterator<Element> it2 = trElement2.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                        Element tdElement = it.next();
                        final String content = tdElement.text();

                        if (it2.hasNext()) {
                            sb.append(formatData(content));
                            sb.append(",");

                        }

                        if (!it2.hasNext()) {
                            String content1 = content.replaceAll(",$", " ");
                            sb.append(formatData(content1));
                            break;
                        } //to remove last placed Commas.

                    }

                    System.out.println(sb.toString());
                    sb.flush();
                    sb.close();


}
```

im trying to `remove` the last `character` which in your case is a `,` at the `instance where it is trying to move to a new line` try replacing with my code
and make sure to `instantiate stringbuffer` with a `space` passed as a string.

Comment: Not working, start getting comma at the last place after doing this.

Comment: made some changes again , bt you might need to take a look at `stringJoiner` this would be very easy with `stringJoiner`

Comment: I tried your code but still the problem exist. I am trying to use stringJoiner but it is giving an error. I guess its happening due to java version i.e. 1.7.

Comment: Thanks @priyamal my issue has been resolved with this technique. I just replace the 'it2' with  'it' in the second if statement.

Answer (score 3):

If you're developing in Java 8, I suggest that you use [StringJoiner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html). With this new class, you don't have to build the string yourself. You can find an example to create a CSV with `StringJoiner` [here](http://javaninja.net/2015/09/creating-a-csv-with-stringjoiner/).

I hope it helps.

Comment: I updated my java version to 8. But, now I am getting new bug i.e. I am getting only single row in the CSV file while it should bring more rows. I am  not using StringJoiner yet.

Comment: You could define a StringJoiner per raw and output them on the console as in your code extract. Let me know if it answers your question.